# Why Social metrics are different for orginal url and utm_source tagged url?

Tags: facebook, analytics, utm

Recently we want to boost a particular webpage in facebook. for tracking purpose i added utm code using google url builder. Since our post is very good we received like ans shares. The next moment i realized the mistake about adding utm to the webpage. check the below images

Likes & Shares for Original blog post
http://sharetally.co/147697/

Likes & Shares for blog post tagged with utm code
http://sharetally.co/147698/

I thought i will receive likes and shares for my original blog post
What could be the mistake?

Comment: Different URLs mean they are treated as two different Open Graph objects, and therefor shares and likes will be counted for each one individually. You can specify the canonical URL, or `og:url` via meta tag though, to point the URL with the tracking code to the “real” URL you want your Open Graph object to be identified by.